# Yargs Module: Not enough arguments provided. Expected 1 but recieved 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, yargs

I am following a tutorial to learn nodeJS. We are creating commands using the Yargs module in a file named app.js. So far everything has worked perfectly until the tutorial requested I change some code at the end of my app.js file. Then I started to get unexpected errors that were not in the original tutorial.

The code worked as predicted when app.js had the line: console.log(yargs.argv)

But the tutorial asked us to replace that line with:
yargs.parse().

console error:

```
    YError: Not enough arguments provided. Expected 1 but received 0.
        at module.exports (C:\Users\officedepot\node_modules\yargs\lib\argsert.js:25
    :13)
        at Object.Yargs.self.parse (C:\Users\officedepot\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js
    :510:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\officedepot\Desktop\nodedemo\nodeapp\command
    s.js:56:7)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    C:\Users\officedepot\node_modules\yargs-parser\index.js:756
      return parse(args.slice(), opts)
                        ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
        at Function.Parser.detailed (C:\Users\officedepot\node_modules\yargs-parser\
    index.js:756:21)
        at Object.Yargs.self._parseArgs (C:\Users\officedepot\node_modules\yargs\yar
    gs.js:941:27)
        at Object.Yargs.self.parse (C:\Users\officedepot\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js
    :533:23)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\officedepot\Desktop\nodedemo\nodeapp\command
    s.js:56:7)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
```

APP.js

```
    const yargs = require('yargs');
    yargs.command({
        command: 'add',
        describe: 'add a new note',
        builder: {
            title: {
                describe: 'Note title',
                demandOption: true,
                type: 'string'
            }
        },
        handler: function(argv){
            console.log('Title: ' + argv.title )
        }
    })


//console.log(yargs.argv); //this worked as predicted
yargs.parse() //this is the new line, which introduced the error shown.
```

Here is what I run in the node CMD:

```
node app.js add --title="My Title"
```

I expect "Title: My Title". But instead received an error.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `node --version` and `npm show yargs version` commands in the command line? I am trying to know the version of node and the module yargs you are using. I am unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks Shivam. I have determined that the installation of yargs must have been corrupted/incomplete in some fashion. Once I did a fresh installation it cleared everything up and now functions appropriately. I am a little confused about how I was able to use yargs at all considering the problem, but regardless of that I have resolved the issue. Thanks